# Can I define the order when using two batches in the Schedule Class?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

```
public class ScheduleOnProjectSum implements Schedulable {
    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC) {
        DeletedSBLBatch dsb = new DeletedSBLBatch();        
        try {
            database.executeBatch(dsb, 200);
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Onhold Schedual Error! Exception! '+e.getMessage());
        }

        CreateSBLBatch  csb = new CreateSBLBatch();
        try {
            database.executeBatch(csb, 200);
        } catch(Exception e){
            system.debug('Onhold Schedual Error! Exception! '+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

We are using two Batch here in Schedule Class. However, the Deleted SBLBatch should be executed first and then the Create SBLBatch should be executed. Can I define the order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

salesforce doesn't guarantee the order of execution of batches in your case. It is possible to implement using batch chaining.

In order to send for execution second batch after the first batch, you can use `finish` method of the first batch. This method executes after all chunks of batches are executed:

```
public class DeletedSBLBatch implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

   public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
      //get records for processing
      return Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1000]);
   }    

   public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Sobject> scope){
       // executes first batch logic
   }

   public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
       // send for execution second batch after first is complete
       Database.executeBatch(new CreateSBLBatch());
   }
}
```

---

Take a look at the [Using Batch Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm)

> To send confirmation emails or execute post-processing operations, use
> the finish method. This method is called after all batches are
> processed.